# Jumping [f]orward to a letter into the next line

Tags: vim

Say that in the following paragraph my cursor lies on the first ***are*** in the first sentence (wish I could highlight it, but I can't so ...). Upon pressing `ff` twice that will get me to ***fools*** in the first sentence, and then to ***of***. Further pressing it will get me nowhere.

```
Some people are confident because they are fools. Leonard had the look of
someone who was confident because, so far, he'd never found reason not to be. He
would step off a high building in the happy state of mind of someone who
intended to deal with the problem of the ground when it presented itself.
```

What would I need to modify so I can "move" across lines, so that further pressing `ff` will make Vim jump into the next lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to modify except Vim's source code. `fFtT` are linewise and there's nothing you can do about it. See `:h left-right-motions`

You could use `/f`, which is not limited to the current line, instead but it's not as fast as it requires another keypress.

Or a plugin like [easymotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526).

Did you know that you can hit `;` to redo the previous `fFtT`?

Comment: Hmpf, just when I thought I was missing only a simple setting somewhere. Wonder why they made it linewise... (will see about easymotion, but I've a feeling it's gonna break something)

Comment: Easymotion doesn't seem to break anything here. I've just started to try to use it so I'm not completely sold.

Comment: No, I ment with some of my other (badly) written plugins. Well, the demo looks interesting so I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of solutions, but none do exactly what you want. Usually in this situation I would do `ff` followed by a series of `;` characters to repeat `f`. When I reach the end of the line I hit `+` and then continue with `;`. Similarly, you can use `,` to go backwards and `0<BS>` to go back a line.

Another option is to write lines with `set wrap` and no hard breaks, but for various reasons users may not find that ideal.

Despite this seeming like nonsense it can actually be useful in some situations. For example, the `:norm` command will skip a line if `ff` doesn't find anything. You can use this for complex `:norm` commands over multiple lines to check for a particular character before you proceed with the command.

## Edit:

There's a plugin that accomplishes this: https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic